# Manually drawing a gradient in iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

If I have two UIColors, what's the best way to draw an even gradient between them over an arbitrarily-sized area?

I am guessing you would create a UIView subclass and use the CG drawing methods in the drawRect method. I just don't know which ones, or if there are any pitfalls to watch out for, like performance. Has anyone done this?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone/1931498#1931498

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll want to use CGGradient. See the iPhone Dev Center "[CGGradient Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGradient/Reference/reference.html)" document.

Comment: This link works better: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: You could provide examples when leaving answer.

Comment: Link-only answers should always provide the critical information in the answer in case the link goes dead.

Answer (score 50):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>    
- (void) setGradient {
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];     
}
```

Don't forget to add QuartzCore library to your project.

Comment: I really like this solution. With code, instead of a reference. IMHO it should get more up-votes.

Answer (score 3):

The Swift way to add Gradient is :

```
    var view : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100))
    var g : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    g.frame = gradientView.bounds
    g.colors = ["000000".UIColor.CGColor , "111111".UIColor.CGColor]
    view.layer.insertSublayer(g, atIndex: 0)
```

`UIColor()` is a helper class for Swift to convert `hex color` to `rgb color`, highly recommended.

Comment: What's `"000000".UIColor.CGColor`?

Comment: @JSmyth It's a Swift's String extension that convert 6 digit String to UIColor. You can easily find it on github.

Comment: @reza-rg I mean I prompted you to mention this in your answer. Not everyone is using that extension in the end. I suggest you add at least a link to the extension. More than that, the answer is fine but it's really easy to go with a standard way of instantiating colors for the sake of simplicity (e.g. `UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor`) as the question is about gradients, not hex-representation of colors. Finally, `UIColor()` is not a helper class, it's a built-in object.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using CAGradientLayer produced a gradient with noticeable stepping
Ended up using this

> http://evilrockhopper.com/tag/cggradient/

As per this question [Gradients on UIView and UILabels On iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

For views that draw text, such as `UILabel`, `UITextView`, and `UITextField`, you should add the gradient inside the `drawRect` function. (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/422208/877032) for an example).

There are some great subclasses of `UILabel`, `UITextView`, and `UITextField` that allow you to add a gradient pretty easily (see [JBGradient on GitHub](https://github.com/carleek/JBGradientTextViews)).

Answer (score 0):

Same-ish solution as @Anton Chikin but a little more robust. Notice the override of `layerClass`... this way, you don't have to worry about setting the frame and the frame is automatically updated upon rotation & resize.

```
class GradientView: UIView {

    var colorA : UIColor = UIColor.greenColor() {
        didSet { updateGradient() }
    }
    var colorB : UIColor = UIColor.blueColor() {
        didSet { updateGradient() }
    }

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        updateGradient()
    }

    func updateGradient() {
        if let gLayer = layer as? CAGradientLayer {
            gLayer.colors = [colorA.CGColor, colorB.CGColor]
        }
    }

}
```

If you're using IB, you can set the properties via "User Defined Runtime Attributes".

If you're not using IB, use the other initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to apply a gradient on the view

```
-(void)applyGradientEffecttoView:(UIView *)aView
 {
     // Create the colors

     UIColor *darkOp = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0];
     UIColor *lightOp =[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f green:255.0f blue:255.0f alpha:0.0];

      // Create the gradient
      CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

      // Set colors
      gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        (id)lightOp.CGColor,
                        (id)darkOp.CGColor,
                        nil];
     gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                          nil];

    // Set bounds
     gradient.frame = aView.bounds;
 
   // Add the gradient to the view

  [aView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}
```