# UITableViewcell UIColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to find out how to set UITableViewCell background color to the "grey" used for example in the official clock application for alarm cells.

I'm unable to find that out in system colors nor elsewhere.

How do I set this color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [Styling UITableViewCells with gradient backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757613/styling-uitableviewcells-with-gradient-backgrounds)

Comment: Gradient method: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/adding-shadow-effects-to-uitableview.html