# Make Background of UIView a Gradient Without Sub Classing

Tags: iphone, uiview, subclass

Is there a way to make the background of a UIView a gradient without subclassing it? I'd rather not use an image file to accomplish this either. It just seems obtuse to have to subclass UIView just to draw a gradient for the background.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `+[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` to produce a patterned background. Example (bring your own CGGradient):

```
// Allocate color space
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
// Allocate bitmap context
CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 320, 480, 8, 4 * 320, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
//allocate myGradient
CGFloat locationList[]  = {0.0f, 1.0f};
CGFloat colorList[]     = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
CGGradientRef myGradient   = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colorList, locationList, 2);
// Draw Gradient Here
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(bitmapContext, myGradient, CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), CGPointMake(320.0f, 480.0f), 0);
// Create a CGImage from context
CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
// Create a UIImage from CGImage
UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
// Release the CGImage
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
// Release the bitmap context
CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
// Release the color space
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
// Create the patterned UIColor and set as background color
[targetView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];
```

It will probably be simpler to just create a `UIView` subclass though. It will use less memory as well.

Comment: there is a memory leak in line #2 where there is no chance to release the result of CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

Comment: Good implementaion. One question though, will this works with the new retina display devices? (I saw that 320x480 is hard coded there)

Comment: @chakrit, it will still work with retina devices, but only render the gradient at 1x resolution; depending on the gradient that may be sufficient. 320x480 is hard coded to make the sample simpler–would be better to use whatever the actual view size is.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev it is a `CGGradientRef` that you create using `CGGradientCreateWithColors`/`CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents`

Answer (score 29):

You could do:

**Swift >= 4.0:**

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = view.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = view.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.red().cgColor, UIColor.white().cgColor]
view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

**Swift <= 2.3:**

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = view.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor]
view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

**Objective-C:**

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Make sure to add the QuartzCore framework to your project as well (at least for Objective-C)...

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: when i use this code i'm getting error like Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAGradientLayer", referenced from:

Comment: @VinothKumar add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: i wrote this "cellForRowAtIndexPath" ,so that i can display gradient view in each cell,and it works fine,now i face a problem,while i scroll up  and down,the gradient color is coming darker and darker.how to solve this?

Comment: @jithin I would post a question with that code that you are using. I think that you are adding the layer each time and it is getting reused by the tableView thus making it a darker shade each time

Comment: @kezi exactly,what you said is right, but how to resolve it?

Comment: @jithin you can remove the sublayer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067578/removing-all-calayers-sublayers OR you can create a new cell each time

Comment: @kezi removing sublayer cause crashing. :(

Comment: @jithin sorry but I posted a bad link. I wouldn't remove all the layers. I would use this answer so you can guarantee you are removing the correct layer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853568/tagging-calayers-in-iphone. Then I would also make sure that the number of sublayers is greater than 0; cause I think what my be happening is that you are removing an important sublayer or you are removing a sublayer from a layer that doesn't have any.

Comment: @jithin if you could post this as a question or send your code to my email: me@kez.io I could take a look and help you with it.

Comment: is it possible to rotate the gradient ? how?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with rpetrich, it would be cleaner to just do the UIView subclass.  For an example of how to do this, see [my response in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone/422208#422208).  If you wanted, you could create a generic gradient UIView subclass and simply place that behind the views you want to have gradient backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

I change the adopted answer to my edition

```
+(void) setBlackGradientToView:(UIView*)targetView
{
    CGRect frame = targetView.frame;
    // Allocate color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    //allocate myGradient
    CGFloat locationList[]  = {0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGFloat colorList[]     = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    CGGradientRef myGradient   = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colorList, locationList, 2);
    // Allocate bitmap context
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, frame.size.width, frame.size.height, 8, 4 * frame.size.width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    //Draw Gradient Here
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(bitmapContext, myGradient, CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), CGPointMake(0, frame.size.height), 0);
    // Create a CGImage from context
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
    // Create a UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    // Release the CGImage
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    // Release the bitmap context
    CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
    // Release the color space
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    //Create the patterned UIColor and set as background color
    [targetView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:uiImage]];
    //return uiImage;
}
```