# Removing all CALayer's sublayers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

I have trouble with deleting all of layer's sublayers. I currently do this manually, but that brings unnecessary clutter. I found many topics about this in google, but no answer.

I tried to do something like this:

```
for(CALayer *layer in rootLayer.sublayers)
{
    [layer removeFromSublayer];
}
```

but it didn't work.

Also, i tried to clone rootLayer.sublayers into separate NSArray, but result was the same.

Any ideas?

Edit:

I thought it works now, but I was wrong. It works good with CALayers, but it doesn't work with CATextLayers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The simplest way to remove all sublayers from a layer is to set the sublayer property to nil:

`rootLayer.sublayers = nil;`

Comment: Does that automatically dealloc the layers within it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes it does (of course, it simply releases the sublayers, and they will only be deallocated if nothing else is retaining them).

Comment: Would this bypass any of the layer events? Not sure if layer has the equivalent of `viewDidDisappear`, `viewDidUnload`, etc...

Comment: Just came across this in the CALayer documentation: "When setting the sublayers property to an array populated with layer objects you must ensure that the layers have had their superlayer set to nil." Says nothing about setting it to nil, but could the same be required here?

Comment: CALayer.superlayer is a readonly property, so you can't set it to nil. I am interested to know if there is some other way of doing this.

Comment: You call `[CALayer removeFromSuperlayer]`.

Comment: I was happy that this solution did not trigger any "collection was mutated while being enumerated" exceptions, but I worried that perhaps the sublayers' `superlayer` property might not be changed -- an issue for me since these layers are owned by another controller. I tested this by temporarily keeping a ref to one of the sublayers (via `sublayers objectAtIndex:0`) and can confirm that its `superlayer` property was indeed nullified.

Comment: I am adding a sublayer to UIButton *bttn, and when I call `bttn.layer.sublayers = nil;` the app crashes. Any hints?

Comment: This totally causes crashing and confusion.

Comment: Don't do this. It causes random crashes after the event.

Comment: Too much side effect

Comment: @odemolliens like what?

Comment: You can broke many other layers. Try you're trick in a UIView inside a UITableViewCell, you will have side effect and crashes

Answer (score 34):

The following should work:

```
for (CALayer *layer in [[rootLayer.sublayers copy] autorelease]) {
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works, and mine would probably too, because the problem was somewhere else.

Comment: You have to use a copy of the sub-layers list: otherwise you will end up modifying the list while iterating over it, which is not really really safe.

Comment: My favorite way for mutating an array by potentially removing objects is to traverse it backwards with a for loop: for (int i = rootLayer.sublayers.count-1; i >= 0; i--) { [[rootLayer.sublayers objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperlayer]; }

Comment: I had some random crashes using this technique. When the main UIView which contained the sublayers was left empty and then was tapped it crashed because there were no layers to hitTest. So a simple solution to avoid that is to set the frame of your UIView to `CGRectZero` .

Answer (score 18):

Swift (short version):

`layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }`

Comment: Nice one! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

```
[rootLayer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
```

Comment: This does work, but I'm curious as to why. Class ref says that the selector method sent in `makeObjectsPerformSelector:` "must not have the side effect of modifying the receiving array." But doesn't `removeFromSuperlayer` modify both the objects in the array (their superlayer property is nullified) and the array itself (it loses its members)?

Comment: I get ````Collection <CALayerArray: 0x60800005e3f0> was mutated while being enumerated. ```` when trying this.

Comment: I strongly suggest to make a copy of sublayers first, then do the removal as the answer showed above, otherwise it will crash as @dbainbridge said.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `rootLayer.sublayers = nil;` can cause a crash (e.g. if, under iOS 8, you call removeFromSuperview twice on the view owning `rootLayer`).

The right way should be:

`[[rootLayer.sublayers copy] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)]`

The call to `copy` is needed so that the array on which `removeFromSuperlayer` is iteratively called is not modified, otherwise an exception is raised.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do this in Xamarin/C#. I had a `UITableViewCell` with some `CAShapeLayers` for borders. All of the above options (including copying the Array and then removing layers caused a crash). The approach that worked for me:

When adding the `CALayer`, I gave it a name:

```
    var border = new CALayer();
    border.BackgroundColor = color.CGColor;
    border.Frame = new  CGRect(x, y, width, height);
    border.Name = "borderLayerName";
    Layer.AddSublayer(border);
```

In `PrepareForReuse` on the `UITableViewCell`, I created a copy of the `SubLayers` property and removed anything that matched the name I assigned earlier:

```
    CALayer[] copy = new CALayer[Layer.Sublayers.Length];
    Layer.Sublayers.CopyTo(copy, 0);
    copy.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "borderLayerName")?.RemoveFromSuperLayer();
```

No crashes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This help me a lot. Thanks buddy.

Comment: this I think is the safest - avoiding error when removing a layer that its not added yet

Answer (score 3):

Indiscriminately removing all sublayers causes nasty crashes in iOS 7, which can occur much later in the program's execution. I have tested this thoroughly using both `rootLayer.sublayers = nil` and `[rootLayer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)]`. There must be a system-created layer that's getting messed up.

You have to keep your own array of layers and remove them yourself:

```
[myArrayOfLayersIAddedMyself makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
```

Comment: This is quite important , removing all sublayers can be dangerous ! In addition to @Nestor 's answer an other way to do this is to use the property name of CALayer to keep track of the ones you add like this : `shapeLayer.name = linesLayerName;` .
Finally remove only Layers that have your name : 

`for (CALayer *layer in [self.layer.sublayers copy]) {
        
        if ([[layer name] isEqualToString:linesLayerName]) {
            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
        }
    }`

Answer (score 3):

Both setting `self.view.layer.sublayers = nil` and `[layer removeFromSuperlayer]` will result in crash if `UIView` contains any subview. Best way to remove `CALayer` from superLayer is by maintaining an array of layers.
For instance that array is arrayOfLayers,

Everytime you add a layer on `UIView.sublayer` add that layer in this array...

For example

```
[arrayOfLayers addObject:layer];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

While removing just call this,

```
[arrayOfLayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply provide an identifier for the CAlayer you have added and  remove it by searching for it. Like so

```
 let spinLayer = CAShapeLayer()
 spinLayer.path = UIBezierPath()
 spinLayer.name = "spinLayer"


  func removeAnimation() {
     for layer in progressView.layer.sublayers ?? [CALayer]()
         where layer.name == "spinLayer" {
           layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using reverse enumeration?

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [rootLayer.sublayers reverseObjectEnumerator];
for(CALayer *layer in enumerator) {
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

Because the group in sublayers are changed during enumeration, if the order is normal.
I would like to know the above code's result.

Comment: Per Apple's documentation, don't do this:
"Enumeration is “safe”—the enumerator has a mutation guard so that if you attempt to modify the collection during enumeration, an exception is raised."

I don't know why it worked, but I would use the method Ben posted.

Comment: I wonder the layers previously in the sublayer were actually released by using the method Ben posted. As David says, fast enumeration prohibits modification its collection.

Comment: I dont know why its down voted - its a standard technique to reverse count through an array when performing a deletion op.

Comment: This works like a charm. i didnt know reverse enumeration made deletion safe, but now i will use it ALL THE TIME!

Comment: OK, i was wrong. This only works because layer.sublayers is an IMMUTABLE array and the "deletion" is handled by the "removeFromSuperlayer" - method. it is still a nice touch, but it's not like i can suddenly use forin-loops with mutable arrays while performing deletion. so izts back to simple for.loops, i guess ;(

Answer (score 2):

I tried to delete just the first sublayer at index 0 and this worked:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([cell.contentView.layer.sublayers count] != 0) {
        [[cell.contentView.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue and found many solutions but none of them are perfect.
Finally from [above answer of pnavk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36652853/6325474) i got the idea. At there the code is for Xamarin/C# users.
The iOS version could be as below:

**Swift 2.3**

```
    if rootLayer.sublayers?.count > 0 {
        rootLayer.sublayers?.forEach {
            if $0.name == "bottomBorderLayer" {
                $0.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }
    }

    let border = CALayer()
    let height = CGFloat(1.0)

    border.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    border.borderWidth = height

    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - height, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)

    border.name = "bottomBorderLayer"
    rootLayer.addSublayer(border)
    rootLayer.masksToBounds = true
```

**Objective-C**

```
if (rootLayer.sublayers.count > 0) {
    for (CALayer *layer in rootLayer.sublayers) {
        if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"bottomBorderLayer"]) {
            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
        }
    }
}

CALayer *border = [[CALayer alloc] init];
CGFloat height = 1.0;

border.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
border.borderWidth = height;

border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
border.name = @"bottomBorderLayer";
[rootLayer addSublayer:border];
rootLayer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
```

The above code will work for bottom border only. You can change the border side as per your requirement.
Here before adding any layer to the controller, I have just run a for loop to check whether any border is already applied or not? 
To identify previously added border I use name property of CALayer. And compare that layer before remove from sublayers.
I have tried the same code before using name property, but It creates random crash. But after using name property and comparing name before remove will solve the crash issue.

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

For swift3+,You can use this.

`yourView.layer.sublayers?.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)`

See here: [Apple API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1641473-removeall)

Or you can:

`yourView.layer.sublayers?.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperlayer()}`

Comment: Unfortunately, these two answers do two different things. The first actually empties the array structure while the second removes each layer from its super layer. I wouldn't recommend the first even if you are running Swift 3+.

Answer (score -1):

What about doing:

```
rootLayer.sublayers = @[];
```

Answer (score -2):

For sure you can do:
`self.layer.sublayers=nil;`
as suggested by Pascal Bourque. But it's better to call the setter for sublayers property:
`[self.layer setSublayers:nil];`
To avoid any clean up issues if there might be.

Comment: Actually, those two lines produce _exactly_ the same code. Dot notation is just syntactic sugar for calling getter and setter methods. Perhaps you were thinking these were instance variables?