# iOS app crashes when home button is pressed (when app is suspended)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, crash

The app works fine, except that it cannot be suspended. Whenever I press the home button the application crashes with the following stack trace:

```
2014-03-27 12:00:31.413 ProjName[2598:60b] -[__NSCFDictionary animationForKey:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17ee4cc0
2014-03-27 12:00:31.415 ProjName[2598:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary animationForKey:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17ee4cc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2fc9cfd3 0x3a77fccf 0x2fca0967 0x2fc9f253 0x2fbee7f8 0x324caf01 0x324b9d83 0x3250e7b9  0x2fc5f1f1 0x2fbd357f 0x305bda3d 0x3253bdcd 0x324bdca5 0x324bd871 0x32521cc9 0x34acbaed 0x34acb6d7 0x2fc67ab7 0x2fc67a53 0x2fc66227 0x2fbd0f4f 0x2fbd0d33 0x34aca663 0x3251c16d 0x10f759 0x3ac8cab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The end user never notices the crash when pressing the home button.  However, when the app is supposed to be resumed, it is relaunched again. No error messages are shown, so the user probably think the application is working normally.  What could be the problem here?

EDIT: 
This is where the exception is thrown (EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1), in Supporting Files in main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
       return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

EDIT2: 
I have now found what causes the problem, but Im still wondering why? If I create a UIView and add this in drawRect the problem occurs.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self.layer setSublayers:nil];

    activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityView.center=CGPointMake(200, 200);
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [self addSubview:activityView];
}
```

This error is possible to reproduce by adding a UIView with this drawRect like this. Can someone explain this behaviour?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   totalMeter = [[UIViewTest alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320.0, 320.0)];
   [self.view addSubview:totalMeter];

}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [totalMeter setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: try adding exceptional break point in Xcode so that it will show you the line where app crashed.

Comment: I was hoping that would work, but no, it shows the same line. Which is in main.m @autoreleasepool

Comment: @Zeezer can you show the stack trace? are you trying to do something when the appdelegate didEnterBackground method?

Comment: I have found the problem, see my edits. However, I cant understand why this happens.

Comment: Does removing `[self.layer setSublayers:nil];` prevent it from crashing?

Comment: Yes it does. But I need to remove the sublayer for other purposes. And  it only crashes when it is supposed to be suspended, so it never crashes near that line of code.

Comment: Can you try the solutions mentioned here and let us know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067578/removing-all-calayers-sublayers

Comment: Tried the three most upvoted answers, all of them crashed the same way.

Comment: is this crash issue occurs in all screens or only in a particular screen

Comment: You mean devices? The same problem occurs on all devices and screens.

Answer (score 0):

```
[__NSCFDictionary animationForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

The problem is that when your application goes in background, somewhere you call the `animationForKey` method on a value of type dictionary, that doesn't implement that method.

Comment: What could produce this behavior, I dont do anything when the application goes in the background that Im aware of.

Comment: I think you have to add some code, I don't know how your application works and I can't help you without read some code.

Comment: As you can see by the example above. This is possible to reproduce and does not involve any method call to animationForKey.

Comment: I'll try it in a test application, hope to find the bug :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `AFNetworking framework` and including `UIActivityIndicatorView+AFNetworking.h`, I think this is an accusation. I had even happen in my work.

So, if you don't use `UIActivityIndicatorView+AFNetworking.h`, just remove it from your project, then rebuild your project, everything will be ok. wish you.

This is the issue in github [AFNetworking issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/2741)