# Tagging CALayers in iPhone

Tags: search, calayer

I am looking for a general way to be able to search for a unique CALayer in a hierarchy without having to remember where the layer is in a hierarchy (and use the sublayer: and superlayer: methods).

I know this is possible with UIViews (which makes flipping views easy) but is it possible for CALayer?

thank you in advance for your help

Peyman

Answer (score 61):

You can also use the name property of the CALayer.

```
[layer setName:@"myKey"];
```

To look it up,

```
- (CALayer *)myLayer {

    for (CALayer *layer in [superLayerOfMyLayer sublayers]) {

            if ([[layer name] isEqualToString:LabelLayerName]) {
                return layer;
            }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. No way to get a layer by name other than walking 'em all? Ahh well, it's better than nothing!

Comment: Could use a property to avoid having to I suppose. It'd be nice to have a way to look it up though.

Answer (score 23):

Apologize. I was being a dunce. CALayer is a key-value coding compliant container so I can create arbitrary values (including tags) in any instance. To create a tag for instance we do:

```
[rootLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:101] forKey:@"PFtag"];
```

thank you

Answer (score 11):

In Swift you can do this

```
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.name = "\(index)"
```

Then to get the layers you can do this

```
for item in self.layer.sublayers! {
    if item.name == "\(index)" {
        item.removeFromSuperlayer()
        item.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be more idiomatic these days to use a where clause on your loop, rather than the if statement: `for item in self.layer.sublayers! where item.name == "\(index)"`. Also probably preferable to not use force unwraps, but that's more subjective.

Comment: I prefer ```self.layer.sublayers?.filter({ $0.name == "xxx" }).forEach..```

Answer (score 6):

A modern safe take on this.

Assign a name to the layer:

```
layer.name = "MyLayer"
```

Then, filter through all sublayers searching for the name:

```
layer.sublayers?
    .filter { layer in return layer.name == "MyLayer" }
    .forEach { layer in
        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! I think you can replace `layer in return layer.name == "MyLayer"` with `$0.name == "MyLayer"`.

Comment: Thanks @koen That is definitely valid, but sometimes I do prefer the clarity of naming it over using the $0. However, both work fine & just comes down to developer preference / enforced style (if applicable)

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to name your **CALayer**:

```
    let shadowLayer = CALayer()
    shadowLayer.name = "myname"
```

After, you just do a search by name:

```
    if let neuBlackLayer = layer.sublayers?.first(where: { $0.name == "myname" }) {
       // do something with your layer
    }
```

same with guard:

```
    guard let neuBlackLayer = layer.sublayers?.first(where: { $0.name == "myname" }) else { return }
    // do something with your layer
```

Added this answer to clarify other's answers:

1. It is clear, no need to filter or loops.
2. It does what asked in question: the way to find a unique layer (there is nothing about removing it from superlayers, etc. )
3. It is written using **Swift 5.1**