# Find the UIImagePickerControllers UIToolBar color and size

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I am implementing the UIImagePickerController and I have 
a last custom step after (1) taking the image (2) use or retake. My final step is
to let the user scale, crop and rotate the image.

Since the UIImagePickerController has a `toolbar` property I assume the bottom bar with the
|cancel camera button| and |retake use| is a toolbar.
I would like to have my final viewController have a toolbar that looks exactly like 
the one the UIImagePicker has.

I fiddled around with it and can see that it seems to be 55 pix high, but I can not figure out
how to draw the gradient. Has anyone done something similar and knows how to apply such a 
gradient to the toolbar?

[image: UIIMagePickerController toolbar]

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either just create background images and use those as the backgrounds for the buttons and the bar, or create a gradient using the Core Graphics framework. You can create a gradient by doing something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844710/make-background-of-uiview-a-gradient-without-sub-classing).

Comment: Thanks Dima, I was fishing for someone who found the actual gradient to use - guess I can color pick the two colors, it looks fairly symmetrical.