# UIColor from multiple color with Gradient effect

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, gradient, cagradientlayer

This question may ask several time. But I want to know exact answer for this. Question is simple, want to **create UIColor from multiple color with Gradient** effect? But I don't want to following concepts. Instead I research to do this by simple way. ex. make colorspace with multiple color and convert directly into UIColor.

More stuff concepts are:

1) [Image creation with CGGradientRef and then convert into UIColor from UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844710/make-background-of-uiview-a-gradient-without-sub-classing)

2) [Drawing gradient color by CGContextDrawLinearGradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone)

3) [Inserting CAGradientLayer to view's layer(see @Mirko Froehlich's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931498/1407017)

Comment: @TheKing Did you see my question fully, first read my question.

Comment: can you explain what you want? Do you want to draw a color gradient?

Comment: No. Simply say, Need gradient color from multiple color. But It's an fast and repeating process in view. So I want to know how can we create it effectively ie costless. If you draw on view means, It will take some time(I know it's toll small). But I don't want.

Comment: Does that mean you want a single color from the gradient? Or do you mean you want to mix multiple colors and take the result as a single color?

Comment: You asked two question.. I think two questions are same. I want one gradient color from mixed of multiple color? Did you get?

Comment: You want a UIColor that represents a gradient, then do you want to use it to set the background colour of some views..? :/ Is it a dynamic gradient or will it always be the same?

Comment: It is dynamic gradient which will gradually change 10-30 times within seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically create a UIView with color gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074539/programmatically-create-a-uiview-with-color-gradient)