# How to create a CGGradient for my UIView subclass?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-graphics

Does anyone know how to create a **CGGradient** that will fill my view,
my current code is this and it fill the **UIView** with a red rectangle I want to have a **gradient** (from black to grey for instance) instead of the rect :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect r;
    r.origin.x=0.;
    r.origin.y=0.;
    r.size.width=rect.size.width;   
    r.size.height=rect.size.height; 
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1., 0., 0., 1.);
    CGContextFillRect (context,r);  
}
```

Comment: Quick tangential tip: your rect setup code will be much cleaner if you use CGRectMake.

Comment: Or a C99-style initializer. `CGRect r = { .origin = CGZeroRect, .size = rect.size };`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I'll use CGRectMake it seems nice to me =)…
C99-style initializer is nice but not enough Cocoa for me :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone/422208#422208) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone), I provide code for drawing a gloss gradient within a UIView.  The colors and drawing positions can be modified from that to form whatever linear gradient you need.

Answer (score 3):

this is a subclass where you can chose the colors

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GradientView : UIView {
    CGGradientRef gradient;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) CGGradientRef gradient;

- (id)initWithGradient:(CGGradientRef)gradient;
- (id)initWithColor:(UIColor*)top bottom:(UIColor*)bot;
- (void)setGradientWithColor:(UIColor*)top bottom:(UIColor*)bot;
- (void)getRGBA:(CGFloat*)buffer;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "GradientView.h"

@implementation GradientView

@synthesize gradient;

- (id)initWithGradient:(CGGradientRef)grad {
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        [self setGradient:grad];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithColor:(UIColor*)top bottom:(UIColor*)bot {
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        [self setGradientWithColor:top bottom:bot];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setGradient:(CGGradientRef)g {
    if(gradient != NULL && g != gradient){
        CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    }
    if(g != gradient){
        CGGradientRetain(g);
    }
    gradient = g;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setGradientWithColor:(UIColor*)top bottom:(UIColor*)bot {
    CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat clr[8];
    [top getRGBA:clr];
    [bot getRGBA:clr+4] ;
    CGGradientRef grad = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgb, clr, NULL, sizeof(clr)/(sizeof(clr[0])*4));
    [self setGradient:grad];
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);
    CGGradientRelease(grad);
}

- (void)getRGBA:(CGFloat*)buffer {
    CGColorRef clr = [self CGColor];
    NSInteger n = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(clr);
    const CGFloat *colors = CGColorGetComponents(clr);
    // TODO: add other ColorSpaces support
    switch (n) {
        case 2:
            for(int i = 0; i<3; ++i){
                buffer[i] = colors[0];
            }
            buffer[3] = CGColorGetAlpha(clr);
            break;
        case 3:
            for(int i = 0; i<3; ++i){
                buffer[i] = colors[i];
            }
            buffer[3] = 1.0;
            break;

        case 4:
            for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i){
                buffer[i] = colors[i];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, gradient, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(0, rect.size.height), 0);
}


- (void)dealloc {
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: I guess the -(void)getRGBA: method should be in a UIColor category, right?

Answer (score 2):

Use [CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGradient/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents) or [CGGradientCreateWithColors](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGradient/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGGradientCreateWithColors) to create the gradient. (The latter takes CGColor objects.) Then, use [CGContextDrawLinearGradient](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextDrawLinearGradient) or [CGContextDrawRadialGradient](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextDrawRadialGradient) to draw it.

A linear gradient will extend infinitely in at least the two directions perpendicular to the line of the gradient. A radial gradient extends infinitely in every direction. To prevent the gradient from spilling outside your view, you'll probably need to add the view's bounds to the clipping path using [CGContextClipToRect](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClipToRect).