# How do I add a gradient to the text of a UILabel, but not the background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, uilabel, gradient

hey, I want to be able to have a gradient fill on the text in a UILabel I know about CGGradient but i dont know how i would use it on a UILabel's text

i found this on google but i cant manage to get it to work

http://silverity.livejournal.com/26436.html

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone

Comment: actually that question is asking how to add a gradient to the background of a uilabel no a gradient to the text itself

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  See below for a way of setting a gradient to the text, not the background.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/7002874/495180

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**(Skip to bottom for full class source code)**

Really useful answers by both Brad Larson and Bach. The second worked for me but it requires an image to be present in advance. I wanted something more dynamic so I combined both solutions into one:

- draw the desired gradient on a UIImage
- use the UIImage to set the color pattern

The result works and in the screenshot below you can see some Greek characters rendered fine too. (I have also added a stroke and a shadow on top of the gradient)

[image: iOS stylized UILabel, the big brown fox]

Here's the custom init method of my label along with the method that renders a gradient on a UIImage (part of the code for that functionality I got from a blog post I can not find now to reference it):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame text:(NSString *)aText {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.text = aText;

        self.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self gradientImage]];

    }
    return self;
}

- (UIImage *)gradientImage
{
    CGSize textSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font];
    CGFloat width = textSize.width;         // max 1024 due to Core Graphics limitations
    CGFloat height = textSize.height;       // max 1024 due to Core Graphics limitations

    // create a new bitmap image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));

    // get context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();       

    // push context to make it current (need to do this manually because we are not drawing in a UIView)
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);                             

    //draw gradient    
    CGGradientRef glossGradient;
    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace;
    size_t num_locations = 2;
    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    CGFloat components[8] = { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  // Start color
                            1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 }; // End color
    rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);
    CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    CGPoint bottomCenter = CGPointMake(0, textSize.height);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, glossGradient, topCenter, bottomCenter, 0);

    CGGradientRelease(glossGradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace); 

    // pop context 
    UIGraphicsPopContext();                             

    // get a UIImage from the image context
    UIImage *gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // clean up drawing environment
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return  gradientImage;
}
```

I'll try to complete that UILabel subclass and post it.

**EDIT**:

The class is done and it's on [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/doukasd). Read about it [here](http://dev.doukasd.com/2011/05/stylelabel-a-uilabel-with-style/)!

Comment: This is the only answer that works with multi-line text, thanks!

Comment: Any chance updating this to Swift 4?

Answer (score 118):

I was looking for a solution and DotSlashSlash has the answer hidden in one of the comments!

For the sake of completeness, the answer and the simplest solution is:

```
UIImage *myGradient = [UIImage imageNamed:@"textGradient.png"];
myLabel.textColor   = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:myGradient];
```

Comment: This works very well! Much cleaner than the core graphics solution!

Comment: great answer. be careful to use `colorWithPatternImage` sparingly though, as it can be a real memory hog.

Comment: Yep this took moments to implement, I agree tick this!

Comment: @Bach If used on a sized-to-fit UIlabel is it possible to resize the pattern image accordingly?

Comment: @luca the image won't be scaled, only repeated in x and y. So if you are using a gradient, make sure the image height is exactly the height of your label, then you can have a flexible width.

Comment: This is nice except that it doesn't allow masking a gradient on an existing color...

Comment: @PsychoDad what do you mean?

Comment: This works, but of course the only draw back to this approach is you must already have a PNG image with the colors you want to apply as the gradient. If you wanted to determine the colors for the gradient at run time, for maybe a slick shadow or blur, then you would need to go with the approach of @Dimitris's answer or better yet my solution.

Comment: Saw this and had to try it out. Works perfectly.  I did have to play with the Graident Image size to get a good fit but this is awesome.

Answer (score 26):

Swift 4.1

```
class GradientLabel: UILabel {
    var gradientColors: [CGColor] = []

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        if let gradientColor = drawGradientColor(in: rect, colors: gradientColors) {
            self.textColor = gradientColor
        }
        super.drawText(in: rect)
    }

    private func drawGradientColor(in rect: CGRect, colors: [CGColor]) -> UIColor? {
        let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        currentContext?.saveGState()
        defer { currentContext?.restoreGState() }

        let size = rect.size
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                        colors: colors as CFArray,
                                        locations: nil) else { return nil }

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.drawLinearGradient(gradient,
                                    start: CGPoint.zero,
                                    end: CGPoint(x: size.width, y: 0),
                                    options: [])
        let gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        guard let image = gradientImage else { return nil }
        return UIColor(patternImage: image)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
label.gradientColors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
```

Comment: superb for horizontal gradient

Comment: I have two labels in a stack view, and it's hiding one of my labels.

Answer (score 21):

**SWIFT 3+**

This solution is based on @Dimitris's answer. It is an extension on the `UILabel` class that will create a gradient over the label's text per your passed `startColor` and `endColor`. The `UILabel` extension is below:

```
extension UILabel {

    func applyGradientWith(startColor: UIColor, endColor: UIColor) -> Bool {

        var startColorRed:CGFloat = 0
        var startColorGreen:CGFloat = 0
        var startColorBlue:CGFloat = 0
        var startAlpha:CGFloat = 0

        if !startColor.getRed(&startColorRed, green: &startColorGreen, blue: &startColorBlue, alpha: &startAlpha) {
            return false
        }

        var endColorRed:CGFloat = 0
        var endColorGreen:CGFloat = 0
        var endColorBlue:CGFloat = 0
        var endAlpha:CGFloat = 0

        if !endColor.getRed(&endColorRed, green: &endColorGreen, blue: &endColorBlue, alpha: &endAlpha) {
            return false
        }

        let gradientText = self.text ?? ""

        let name:String = NSFontAttributeName
        let textSize: CGSize = gradientText.size(attributes: [name:self.font])
        let width:CGFloat = textSize.width
        let height:CGFloat = textSize.height

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: width, height: height))

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return false
        }

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)

        let glossGradient:CGGradient?
        let rgbColorspace:CGColorSpace?
        let num_locations:size_t = 2
        let locations:[CGFloat] = [ 0.0, 1.0 ]
        let components:[CGFloat] = [startColorRed, startColorGreen, startColorBlue, startAlpha, endColorRed, endColorGreen, endColorBlue, endAlpha]
        rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        glossGradient = CGGradient(colorSpace: rgbColorspace!, colorComponents: components, locations: locations, count: num_locations)
        let topCenter = CGPoint.zero
        let bottomCenter = CGPoint(x: 0, y: textSize.height)
        context.drawLinearGradient(glossGradient!, start: topCenter, end: bottomCenter, options: CGGradientDrawingOptions.drawsBeforeStartLocation)

        UIGraphicsPopContext()

        guard let gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return false
        }

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.textColor = UIColor(patternImage: gradientImage)

        return true
    }

}
```

And usage:

```
let text = "YAAASSSSS!"
label.text = text
if label.applyGradientWith(startColor: .red, endColor: .blue) {
    print("Gradient applied!")
}
else {
    print("Could not apply gradient")
    label.textColor = .black
}
```

[image: YAAASSSSS!]

---

**SWIFT 2**

```
class func getGradientForText(text: NSString) -> UIImage {

    let font:UIFont = UIFont(name: "YourFontName", size: 50.0)!
    let name:String = NSFontAttributeName
    let textSize: CGSize = text.sizeWithAttributes([name:font])
    let width:CGFloat = textSize.width         // max 1024 due to Core Graphics limitations
    let height:CGFloat = textSize.height       // max 1024 due to Core Graphics limitations

    //create a new bitmap image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height))

    // get context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // push context to make it current (need to do this manually because we are not drawing in a UIView)
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context!)

    //draw gradient
    let glossGradient:CGGradientRef?
    let rgbColorspace:CGColorSpaceRef?
    let num_locations:size_t = 2
    let locations:[CGFloat] = [ 0.0, 1.0 ]
    let components:[CGFloat] = [(202 / 255.0), (197 / 255.0), (52 / 255.0), 1.0,  // Start color
                                (253 / 255.0), (248 / 255.0), (101 / 255.0), 1.0] // End color
    rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);
    let topCenter = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    let bottomCenter = CGPointMake(0, textSize.height);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, glossGradient, topCenter, bottomCenter, CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsBeforeStartLocation);

    // pop context
    UIGraphicsPopContext();

    // get a UIImage from the image context
    let gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // clean up drawing environment
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return  gradientImage;
}
```

Props to @Dimitris

Comment: Not working when I put it to ImageView the whole view is yellow and no text in it...

Comment: You are right @J.Doe. I have updated my answer with a solution for Swift 3+. Also I have included my own twist with an extension of `UILabel` that will place the gradient in a `UIColor` and apply it to the label itself. Please let me know if there are any other issues.

Comment: I exactly needed this :)

Comment: thank you for this. it's 2018 and gradient text color is still hard thing to implement.

Comment: Epic, how can i make the gradient horizontal instead?

Comment: @grantespo Change this line for horizontal gradient. `let bottomCenter = CGPoint(x: textSize.width, y: 0)`

Answer (score 14):

The example you provide relies on private text drawing functions that you don't have access to on the iPhone.  <strike>The author provides an example of how to do this using public API in a [subsequent post](http://silverity.livejournal.com/27704.html).</strike> His later example uses a gradient image for the color of the text. (Unfortunately, it appears his blog has since been removed, but see [Bach's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4558480/19679) for the approach he used.)

If you still want to draw the gradient for your text color in code, it can be done by subclassing UILabel and overriding -drawRect: to have code like the following within it:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", 20.0f, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextClip);
CGContextSetTextPosition(context, 0.0f, round(20.0f / 4.0f));
CGContextShowText(context, [self.text UTF8String], strlen([self.text UTF8String]));

CGContextClip(context);

CGGradientRef gradient;
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace;
size_t num_locations = 2;
CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
CGFloat components[8] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  // Start color
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.1 }; // End color

rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;
CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), 0.0f);
CGPoint midCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, topCenter, midCenter, 0);

CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace);         

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

One shortcoming of this approach is that the Core Graphics functions I use don't handle Unicode text properly.

What the code does is it flips the drawing context vertically (the iPhone inverts the normal Quartz coordinate system on for the Y axis), sets the text drawing mode to intersect the drawn text with the clipping path, clips the area to draw to the text, and then draws a gradient.  The gradient will only fill the text, not the background.

I tried using NSString's -drawAtPoint: method for this, which does support Unicode, but all the characters ran on top of one another when I switched the text mode to kCGTextClip.

Comment: thanks for that :) i simiply just used the pattern image method

 label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:gradientImage;

Comment: @PsychoDad - Unfortunately, it looks like the entire blog of his has been removed, but the key information from it is captured in Bach's answer, and the rest of the answer here still stands. Dimitris even has expanded on this in his answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

There is a really simple solution for this! Here's how you add gradient colors to UILabel text.

We will achieve this in just two steps:

1. Create Gradient Image
2. Apply Gradient Image As textColor to UILabel

**1.Create Gradient Image**

```
extension UIImage {
    static func gradientImageWithBounds(bounds: CGRect, colors: [CGColor]) -> UIImage {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = colors

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

Use this as follows:

```
let gradientImage = UIImage.gradientImageWithBounds(bounds: myLabel.bounds, colors: [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor])
```

⠀

**2.Apply Gradient Image As textColor to UILabel**

```
myLabel.textColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: gradientImage)
```

⠀

**Note:**

If you want the gradient to be horizontal, just add these two lines to gradientLayer instance:

```
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
```

⠀

**Note 2:**

The UIImage extension function works with other UIViews too; not just UILabel! So feel free to use this method no matter which UIView you use to apply gradient color.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I'm doing in Swift 3

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timerLabel.textColor = UIColor(patternImage: gradientImage(size: timerLabel.frame.size, color1: CIColor(color: UIColor.green), color2: CIColor(color: UIColor.red), direction: .Left))
}

func gradientImage(size: CGSize, color1: CIColor, color2: CIColor, direction: GradientDirection = .Up) -> UIImage {

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CILinearGradient")
    var startVector: CIVector
    var endVector: CIVector

    filter!.setDefaults()

    switch direction {
    case .Up:
        startVector = CIVector(x: size.width * 0.5, y: 0)
        endVector = CIVector(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height)
    case .Left:
        startVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: size.height * 0.5)
        endVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: size.height * 0.5)
    case .UpLeft:
        startVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: 0)
        endVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: size.height)
    case .UpRight:
        startVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: 0)
        endVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: size.height)
    }

    filter!.setValue(startVector, forKey: "inputPoint0")
    filter!.setValue(endVector, forKey: "inputPoint1")
    filter!.setValue(color1, forKey: "inputColor0")
    filter!.setValue(color2, forKey: "inputColor1")

    let image = UIImage(cgImage: context.createCGImage(filter!.outputImage!, from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))!)
    return image
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
yourLabel.textColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "ur gradient image name ")!)
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted either!! Again, although not programmatic, works very well + minimal.

Answer (score 2):

**Simplest Swift 3 Solution**

Add an image to your project assets or create one programmatically then do the following:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myGradient.png")!
label.textColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: image)
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted! Although not programmatic, works very well + minimal.

Answer (score 2):

## SwiftUI

Although we use `Text` in SwiftUI instead of UILabel, If you consider how to apply a gradient on a `Text`, you should apply it as a `mask`. But since gradients are stretchable, you can make a simple extension like this:

```
extension View {
    func selfSizeMask<T: View>(_ mask: T) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self.opacity(0)
            mask.mask(self)
        }.fixedSize()
    }
}
```

---

## Demo

And then you can assign any gradient or other type of view as a self-size mask like:

```
Text("Gradient is on FIRE !!!")
    .selfSizeMask(
        LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .yellow]),
            startPoint: .bottom,
            endPoint: .top)
    )
```

[image: Demo]

<sub>This method contains some bonus advantages that you can see here **[in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63933797/5623035)**</sub>

Answer (score -1):

You could sub-class out UILable and do the draw method yourself.  That would probably be the more difficult approach, there might be an easier way.

Comment: yeh i have done that but it the gradient does fill over the text it goes over the whole view

Comment: i mean it *doesnt* fill over the text