# How to I add gradient color or image to Text in iPhone dev

Tags: iphone

I want to add a gradient color to my UILabel or any text on my iPhone screen. I want to know the ways to do it. Both Using interface and programatically.

tnx

Comment: This is very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266179/how-to-add-a-gradient-on-a-uilabel

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I expanded on my previous comment after all and created a little subclass of UILabel for this purpose. You can read about it [here](http://dev.doukasd.com/2011/05/stylelabel-a-uilabel-with-style/) where you can also get the code.

This is the result:

[image]

Old reply:

Please see my reply to this question: [How do I add a gradient to the text of a UILabel, but not the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266179/how-do-i-add-a-gradient-to-the-text-of-a-uilabel-but-not-the-background/6008005#6008005)

Shows the code needed to achieve what you are after.

Answer (score -1):

In in the interface, you should be able to select the label and go to inspector (apple + 1) and change the color from there.

Programmatically, use the following property.

[UILabel textColor property reference](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/textColor)

Example:

[mylabel setTextColor: [UIColor redColor]];

[UIColor reference](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/).

To gradient, all you have to do is extend this a little.
Break the text that you want to gradient into a group of labels, group them with a list of some sort, and iterate over the grouped labels and apply a textColor. This sort of gradient is trivial and derives immediately from the documentation provided.

Comment: I said gradient and not just color.