# Apply gradient to ShapeLayer's stroke?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently trying to implement a circle with an animated stroke - which works fine (see image below).

For a while now, I've been trying to add a gradient to the circle's stroke. I'm am using a piece of code I already have used to underline a `UITextField`.

**How can I apply my code for the gradient to the `shapeLayer`'s stroke?**

**Circle:**

```
let color = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 95/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1)

let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let center = CGPoint(x: circleView.frame.size.width/2, y: circleView.frame.size.height / 1.3)
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 120, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground.cgColor
trackLayer.lineWidth = 14
trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0

circleView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
circleView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

**Code Gradient:**

```
let color = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 95/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
let sndColor = UIColor(red: 124/255, green: 206/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1).cgColor

let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.colors = [color, sndColor]
gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.8]
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
let width = CGFloat(3.0)
gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)

self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
self.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

**Current Version:**
[image: Example]

**Edit:**
My stroke animation:

```
func animateStroke() {
        if !animated {
            animated = true

            let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
            var value: Double?

            if expectedCosts <= monthlyPrice {
                value = 1
            } else {
                value = monthlyPrice / expectedCosts
            }

            basicAnimation.toValue = value
            basicAnimation.duration = 1.5
            basicAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
            basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            basicAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)


            shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "strokeAnimation")

        }
    }
```

Stroke code:

```
func displayCircle() {
        let color = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 95/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1)

        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let center = CGPoint(x: circleView.frame.size.width/2, y: circleView.frame.size.height / 1.3)
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 120, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 14
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0

        circleView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        circleView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        let sndColor = UIColor(red: 124/255, green: 206/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1).cgColor

        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [color, sndColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.8]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        gradient.frame = circleView.bounds

        gradient.mask = trackLayer
        circleView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying a Gradient to CAShapeLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733966/applying-a-gradient-to-cashapelayer)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437581/how-to-fill-a-bezier-path-with-gradient-color/41440222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let color = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 95/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1)
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let center = CGPoint(x: masterlayer.frame.size.width/2, y: masterlayer.frame.size.height / 1.3)
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 120, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 14
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    trackLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.duration = 3
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1
    animation.beginTime =  0.00001
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    trackLayer.add(animation, forKey: "strokeEnd" + "\(index)")


    let color1 = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 95/255, blue: 24/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let sndColor = UIColor(red: 124/255, green: 206/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [color1, sndColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.8]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    let width = CGFloat(3.0)
    gradient.frame = masterlayer.bounds

    gradient.mask = trackLayer
    circleView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Working code for you problem

Add gradient on circleView.layer and set tracker layer as mask layer for graient

Comment: Thanks! Please find the new code + my animation inside of the edit - with this version, the stroke in the background has a gradient, but I want the animated `shapeLayer`'s stroke to have a gradient. Btw what do you mean by `masterLayer` - `circleView`?

Comment: yes , please replace masterLayer with circleView.layer

Comment: gradient.mask = trackLayer
    circleView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

Comment: this is main thing

Comment: Using `gradient.mask = trackLayer` applies the gradient to the whole stroke - can I somehow apply it only to the stroke in the foreground (blue stroke) which doesn't fill the whole shape's stroke. You can find my code in the edit to my initial question.