# NSString drawInRect overlaps all characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I am attempting to fill some text with a gradient-fill, where by I set the text drawing mode to clipping, and then paint a gradient-fill.
The problem is, whenever I set the text drawing mode to clip, every character of the text string is placed on top of each other, rather than being painted in a sequence to form a word - it is most bizarre!

My code looks like this:

```
CGRect r = CGRectInset(self.frame, 55, 8);      

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGFloat components[8] = {44/255, 54/255, 66/255, 1.0
            ,75/255, 92/255, 111/255, 1.0};
CGFloat locations[2] = {0, 1};

// draw the text's gradient fill
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, components, locations, 2);

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextClip);


[monthString drawInRect:r withFont:f lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the UIKit NSString additions that let you do drawInRect:withFont: and the like don't play well with the kCGTextClip drawing mode.  I've seen the same behavior, and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266179/how-do-i-add-a-gradient-to-the-text-of-a-uilabel-but-not-the-background/1267638#1267638) I provide code to fill text with a gradient using pure Quartz drawing calls.  The downside to this approach is that you are limited to the MacRoman text encoding, which lacks support for many Unicode symbols.