# Creating a gradient fill for text using [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]

Tags: objective-c, ios4, core-graphics, uilabel

I want to create a gradient for the fill color of my text. Currently I am doing it by setting the color of a UILabel's text as

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GradientFillImage.png"];
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

Where `GradientFillImage.png` is a simple image file with a linear gradient painted on it.

This works fine until I want to resize the font. Since the image file is of constant dimensions and does not resize when I resize the font, the gradient fill for the font gets messed up.
How do I create a custom size pattern image and apply it as a fill pattern for text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Basically, we can override `drawRectInText` and use our own pattern to color the fill. The advantage of doing this is that we can resize the image into our pattern frame.

First we create a CGPattern object and define a callback to draw the pattern. We also pass the size of the label as a parameter in the callback. We then use the pattern that is drawn in the callback and set it as the fill color of the text:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //set gradient as a pattern fill
    CGRect info[1] = {rect};
    static const CGPatternCallbacks callbacks = {0, &drawImagePattern, NULL};
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0);

    CGPatternRef pattern = CGPatternCreate((void *) info, rect, transform, 10.0, rect.size.height, kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing, true, &callbacks);
    CGColorSpaceRef patternSpace = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(NULL);
    CGFloat alpha = 1.0;
    CGColorRef patternColorRef = CGColorCreateWithPattern(patternSpace, pattern, &alpha);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(patternSpace);
    CGPatternRelease(pattern);
    self.textColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:patternColorRef];
    self.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];
}
```

The callback draws the image into the context. The image is resized as per the frame size that is passed into the callback.

```
void drawImagePattern(void *info, CGContextRef context)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FontGradientPink.png"];
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    CGRect *rect = info;
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect[0], imageRef);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've just finished a UIColor class extension that makes this a 1 line + block thing.

https://github.com/bigkm/UIColor-BlockPattern

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,10.0,10.0);

[UIColor colorPatternWithSize:rect.size andDrawingBlock:[[^(CGContextRef c) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FontGradientPink.png"];
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, [image CGImage]);
} copy] autorelease]];
```

Comment: Nice work @bigkm. This definitely adds an easy to use wrapper around some messy code.