# How to draw gradient along the arc

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am developing a Mac app, I want to draw a view like a radar, I find no method to draw gradient color along the arc. The existing method only draw gradient towards one direction.

Comment: gradient drawing is always a costly affair, it shuold be used with a purpose. in your case you can use an image.

Comment: How about creating an image in photoshop that looks like your radar and simply rotate it?

Comment: I don't want to use image, because the size of the radar view will change

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266179/how-do-i-add-a-gradient-to-the-text-of-a-uilabel-but-not-the-background/4558480#4558480

Comment: There's probably a way to get the fuzzy trailing effect with core animation effects.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Drawing images, especially rotated (so no straight-across copy or composite), ain't cheap, either.

Comment: @PeterHosey: after seeing your sample I came to know "His actual requirement". I was thinking just a cirlce with a gradient, something darker in center and lighter in border. So you are correct(as always) rotation isn't cheap eithr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is an angle gradient. I've written [a Core Image filter that generates an angle gradient](https://gist.github.com/boredzo/5691822); give it an opaque color (e.g., green) for the start color and the completely-transparent version of that color for the middle and end colors.

[image: Angle gradient with green, transparent green, and transparent green.]

(The filter's output is actually infinite in extent and centered at the origin, so you'll need to mask it out to a circle and use an affine transform at one level or another to get it into the right position.)

Extra credit: In the kernel code for that filter (near the start of the .m), there's a line that starts the gradient at straight-up (90°) rather than straight-right. You could change the code, both of the filter and of the kernel, to make this a parameter (like `inputStartColor` et al) that you could vary over time, using a CABasicAnimation or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a combination of axial and radial gradients and probably also some clipping paths. You can find all of this documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html).

You can also use `colorWithPatternImage:` to stroke any lines you're drawing.