# iOS7 "Slide to unlock" animation on a UILabel

Tags: ios, animation

How to make an animation similar to "Slide to unlock" text on a UILabel? (The text gradient is animated left->right) and then the text color adapts to the background.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266179/how-do-i-add-a-gradient-to-the-text-of-a-uilabel-but-not-the-background/4558480#4558480 + NSAnimation I suppose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the key to performing this effect is `CALayer` [`mask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/mask). You can attach a second CALayer to any existing layer as its mask. Then:

> The [mask] layer’s alpha channel determines how much of the [parent] layer’s content
>   and background shows through. Fully or partially opaque pixels allow
>   the underlying content to show through but fully transparent pixels
>   block that content.

So the text is going to be the mask and the moving colour is going to be the parent.

The easiest way to deal with the text will be to use a [`CATextLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). The easiest way to make the colour gradient will be [`CAGradientLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html).

To animate the gradient you can use Core Animation, since all properties are animatable. I guess `locations` is likely to be the best way to achieve the sliding animation.

For convenience you'll probably want to wrap all of that up into a `UIView`, but you can add layers directly if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the text be the parent and the colour be the mask instead?

Comment: @Pinch I guess it works either way around, now you mention it, but your way around would allow for much more direct use of text attributes; if you want the text to be blue then just set the string attribute. If you want different characters to be different colours then just do that. No need to offer specialised hooks to adjust the colour of the gradient layer because that's always just opaque to transparent.