# How do I draw a horizontal shadow?

Tags: ios, uikit

How do I draw a horizontal shadow under the bottom of a view?

Currently, I'm drawing it like this

```
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowRadius = 2
    
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath()
    shadowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height))
    shadowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
    shadowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height + shadowHeight))
    shadowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height + shadowHeight))
    shadowPath.close()
    layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
```

But I end up with a small vertical shadow.

[image: Shadow]

I'm hoping to just cut off all the vertical shadow like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong tool for the job. CALayer's shadow property is meant to simulate the look of a real-world shadow, of course, and for that use it makes sense that the shadow doesn't just stop at the corner, but wraps around it. To get the look that you're describing, [draw a gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38592351/643383) instead. Here's some code:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5).cgColor,
                        UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor]
gradientLayer.frame = layer.bounds
gradientLayer.anchorPoint = layer.anchorPoint
layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

And with that I get:

[image: gray gradient]

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that CALayer's shadow property is meant to simulate the look of a real-world shadow 