# Fill text with an image

Tags: ios, text, swift3, ios10

I have a label with some text in, that is currently just set to the default colour and fill.
I also have an abstract image.

How can you use the image to fill the text so that the text looks patterned?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266179/how-do-i-add-a-gradient-to-the-text-of-a-uilabel-but-not-the-background

Comment: These deal with gradients as opposed to images, and are written in Objective C which I have no idea how to use.

Comment: What actually you what, please show Image for more clearance of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIColor can be created from a pattern image, so anywhere you can use a UIColor you can use an image.

```
    label.textColor = UIColor(patternImage: image));
```

Comment: Very useful - how would I use an image from a location in the project?  (that has been dragged and dropped in)

Comment: UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfYourImage.png"];

Comment: let image = UIImage(named:"name.png")