# Swift - Working With Gradients

Tags: swift, button, colors, label, gradient

I have encountered a problem involving setting gradients for labels and buttons. I know this question has been asked a lot, but no answer has seemed to solve my problem. Here is the screen as I want it to look:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var logoLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let loginButtonGradient = createBlueGreenGradient(from: loginButton.bounds)
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(loginButtonGradient, at: 0)

        signUpButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let signUpButtonGradient = createBlueGreenGradient(from: signUpButton.bounds)
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(signUpButtonGradient, at: 0)

        logoLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let logoLabelGradient = createBlueGreenGradient(from: logoLabel.bounds)
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(logoLabelGradient, at: 0)

        loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 100
        signUpButton.layer.cornerRadius = 100
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func createBlueGreenGradient(from bounds: CGRect) -> CAGradientLayer{
        let topColor = UIColor(red: 84/255, green: 183/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1)
        let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 119/255, green: 202/255, blue: 151/255, alpha: 1)
        let gradientColors: [UIColor] = [topColor, bottomColor]

        let gradientLocations: [NSNumber] = [0.0, 1.0]

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
        gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds

        return gradientLayer
    }
```

And this is the wrong result:

[image]

Somebody please help me. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Apply Gradient to background view of iOS Swift App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380535/how-to-apply-gradient-to-background-view-of-ios-swift-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of issue with your code.

- Divide the color with `Float` number instead of `Int` means it should be `255.0` not `255`.
- Now for `colors` property of `CAGradientLayer` you need to set array of `CGColor` not array of `UIColor`.
- Also set `startPoint` and `endPoint` property of `CAGradientLayer` to make horizontal gradient color.
- Currently you are adding this `GradientLayer` in your `self.view` instead of its specific button.
- Set the `cornerRadius` of your button on basis of its height not with some constant `100` also after setting `cornerRadius` you need to also set `masksToBounds` property of layer to `true`.
- Now for your logo label, you cannot set `textColor` as `Gradient` color directly what you need to do is draw the desired gradient on a `UIImage` and then use that `UIImage` to set the color pattern for your `Label` check this [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266179/how-do-i-add-a-gradient-to-the-text-of-a-uilabel-but-not-the-background) for that.

---

After making all this changes your code should be like.

```
func createBlueGreenGradient(from bounds: CGRect) -> CAGradientLayer{
    let topColor = UIColor(red: 84/255.0, green: 183/255.0, blue: 211/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 119/255.0, green: 202/255.0, blue: 151/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let gradientColors = [topColor, bottomColor]

    let gradientLocations: [NSNumber] = [0.0, 1.0]
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations
    //Set startPoint and endPoint property also
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    return gradientLayer
}
```

Now set `gradientLayer` in `viewDidLoad` this way.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let loginButtonGradient = createBlueGreenGradient(from: loginButton.bounds)
    self.loginButton.layer.insertSublayer(loginButtonGradient, at: 0)

    let signUpButtonGradient = createBlueGreenGradient(from: signUpButton.bounds)
    self.signUpButton.layer.insertSublayer(signUpButtonGradient, at: 0)

    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = loginButton.frame.size.height / 2
    loginButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    signUpButton.layer.cornerRadius = signUpButton.frame.size.height / 2
    signUpButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh my goodness I had the same problem, but played around with it. This is caused because you didnt add `.cgcolor`. For example :

```
 let topColor = UIColor(red: 84/255, green: 183/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
 let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 119/255, green: 202/255, blue: 151/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
 let gradientColors = [topColor, bottomColor]
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your method like this:

```
func createBlueGreenGradient(from bounds: CGRect) -> CAGradientLayer{
    let topColor = UIColor(red: 84/255, green: 183/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 119/255, green: 202/255, blue: 151/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let gradientColors = [topColor, bottomColor]

    let gradientLocations: [NSNumber] = [0.0, 1.0]

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds

    return gradientLayer
  }
```