# Is it possible to have text color be a range of colors?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to a text color start from 1 RGB value and transition to another value? Or do I need to make it an asset and import it?

[image: Example]

I know you can do something similar using `NSSAttribute` but from the examples I've seen you can only change a range of characters in the string.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266179/how-do-i-add-a-gradient-to-the-text-of-a-uilabel-but-not-the-background  OTOH, if it doesn't need to be dynamic, an asset may be easier.

Comment: If you can do it for a range of characters surely ALL the characters IS a range of character (but is them all?)