# How can I make a UIView glossy and shiny?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, interface, sdk

I'm coding an iPhone app annd I currently have a View that looks like this:

[alt text http://drop.io/download/public/hzkqdxyhlev1qul5hx3z/b7fbcecca653fb1a4961f2aecca5ba76c614ad0b/4009e6e0-fa41-012c-64cb-f7b7db223b21/410e4f50-fa41-012c-a999-f4d9d7fd044b/v2/thumbnail_large](http://drop.io/download/public/hzkqdxyhlev1qul5hx3z/b7fbcecca653fb1a4961f2aecca5ba76c614ad0b/4009e6e0-fa41-012c-64cb-f7b7db223b21/410e4f50-fa41-012c-a999-f4d9d7fd044b/v2/thumbnail_large)

I'm wondering if there is a way to make it shiny and glossy like the Phone.app call screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a semi-transparent image that looks like glass, and overlay it.

A competent graphic designer can help you. You can either find someone the usual way, or get someone from crowdspring.om or 99designs.com. Almost anyone with decent PS skills can make an image have a sheen.

You can even Google *sheen image photoshop* and I bet it will tell you how.

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking to draw glossy gradients on UIViews, I provide some code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone/422208#422208) to do that.

Going beyond that, I have [published the source code](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/QuartzExamples.zip) for a sample application which shows how to draw even more polished glossy buttons and how to replicate the glossy highlights that Apple uses in some of the built-in user interface elements (in this case, I replicate UIAlertView's style).

This application was written for the class I teach on advanced iPhone development, for which the course notes are available [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/AdvancediPhoneApps.zip) in VoodooPad format.  The section on Quartz 2D explains how this drawing code works.

Comment: This answer is better than my answer... my answer is kind of a hack. My answer may be easier to execute for the Quartz uninitiated, but the OP would learn a lot from this method.

Comment: @Andrew Johnson Good support ... I liked it.It's really the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should find/design custom graphics for the button you want and then dress them on a UIButton.

You may also consider using a readily available [custom button component](http://www.binpress.com/app/glossy-button-for-ios/968).

[image]