# UITableViewCell with 'ball' like calendar App

Tags: iphone, uitableview

in the iPhone Calendar app, the view to select the calendar for a particular event has a coloured circle next to the calendar name, drawn with a graduated/3D effect of a ball.

Does anyone have any sample code for how this is drawn - I can draw a solid circle in the UITableViewCell, but I'm not sure how to get the 3D effect.

Thanks.

Comment: I just looked at Calendar on my iPhone and I don't see the ball you're talking about??

Comment: It's on the view where you pick the calender that a new event is added to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do this with a [CAGradientLayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) using a radial gradient, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone/1931498#1931498).

Also, take a look at the [documentation on Gradients](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH207-TPXREF101).

[alt text http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Art/shaded_sphere.gif](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Art/shaded_sphere.gif)