# Color gradient of a line with CoreGraphics

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-graphics

I need a line that changes color along the path (which could be approximated by a linear gradient in one direction, if that is easier).

Is it possible to draw the path of a CAShapeLayer so that it has a color gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use a CAShapeLayer as a mask for a CAGradientLayer by setting it to the CAGradientLayer's `mask` property.  This might give you the gradient along the line you are seeking.

Otherwise, follow the code example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985359/how-to-fill-a-path-with-gradient-in-drawrect/2985460#2985460) to draw a path using Core Graphics, clip to it using `CGContextClip()`, and then draw a gradient which will only appear within the drawn path.