# how can I fill in drawRect with color

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a drawRect and I want to fill in the rect specified with a certain color. How do I do so? So far I have tried the following:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
         CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithWhite:29/255.f alpha:1.0].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
}
```

This doesn't seem to work

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985359/how-to-fill-a-path-with-gradient-in-drawrect

Comment: Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800278/iphone-draw-transparent-rectangle-on-uiview-to-reveal-view-beneath

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
[[UIColor colorWithWhite:29/255.f alpha:1.0] setFill];
UIRectFill(rect);
```

This is the simplest way