# How can I add a gloss effect to an image?

Tags: iphone, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I have created an application which captures an image using the iPhone camera and puts the image onto a button.

Before I do this I would like to add a gloss effect similar to that used on icons on the iPhone home screen.

Is that possible to do, and if so, how can it be done?

Comment: What are you expecting this to look like? The iPhone can't capture a 3d image, and it can't display 3d, so I have no idea what you are expecting here.

Comment: @jrturton i know that iPhone can't capture 3d images and i am just expecting that the image should be show in 3d way .and what i am exactly want to do like this application `iMessage` see this link http://iphone.appstorm.net/general/app-news/what-is-imessage-and-how-do-i-use-it/

Comment: Do you mean it should have the gloss effect on it like the icon at the top of that article?

Comment: Ok, I've reworded your question, I think "3d" is the wrong thing to ask for. I hope that is OK.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541457/iphone-glossy-icons-using-core-graphics