# Display a rendered icon in UImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a 57x57 png icon image which I use as my app's main icon. How do I programatically use the iOS's rendering system to produce a glossy effect in the same way the icon is rendered in the home screen? I would preferbably like to use a Uimage passing it with the raw image.

There doesn't seem to be a class called UIPrerenderedIcon to accomplish this, although there is a property in that settings?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, maybe it will help you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541457/iphone-glossy-icons-using-core-graphics][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541457/iphone-glossy-icons-using-core-graphics

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a weird hack, but why not just go to your home screen on the simulator, take a screen shot, and cut it out from there via PhotoShop, InkScape, or something similar? It might be the quickest way to accomplish this.