# Memory Errors when using CAGradientLayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, quartz-graphics

I am using CAGradientLayer to create a background layer, as described in this answer to this question: [Gradients on UIView and UILabels On iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone/422208#422208)

However when I use this code I get a exc_bad_access error with a reference to CGColorSpaceGetModel.

```
UILabel *headerText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width -10, 18)];    

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

gradient.bounds = headerText.bounds;

UIColor *topColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.5647 green:0.6235 blue:0.6667 alpha:1.0];

UIColor *bottomColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.7216 green:0.7569 blue:0.7843 alpha:1.0];

NSArray *gradientColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:topColor, bottomColor, nil];

gradient.colors = gradientColors;

[headerText.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Any idea what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `CGColorRefs` not `UIColor`... there is a property on `UIColor` to get the `CGColorRef`....

```
NSArray *gradientColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(id)topColor.CGColor, (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
```

Comment: I hope, you meant "As viking…" ;)

Answer (score 1):

`gradient.colors` need to be `CGColor`, not `UIColor`.

try

```
NSArray *gradientColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(id)topColor.CGColor, (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CGColor instead of UIColor:

```
    NSArray *gradientColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:topColor.CGColor, 
bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
```