# iOS UITableView: assign background color as gradient using CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4.3, cagradientlayer

I just started playing with the Master-Detail view template in Xcode 4.3 and I am trying to change the background color of master and set it to a color gradient.
Here is what I tried:

Colors.m

```
#import "Colors.h"

@implementation Colors

+ (UIColor *) navigationMenuGradientTop
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:213.0f/255.0f green:91.0f/255.0f blue:92.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}

+ (UIColor *) navigationMenuGradientBottom
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:188.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:1.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];    
}

+ (CAGradientLayer *) navigationMenuGradient
{
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)self.navigationMenuGradientTop, self.navigationMenuGradientBottom, nil];
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.colors = colors;

    return gradientLayer;
}
@end
```

MasterViewController.m

```
import "Colors.h"

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [Colors navigationMenuGradient];
    bgLayer.frame = tableView.bounds;
    [tableView.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];

    return cell;
}
```

Upon running I get the following error in `main` - `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xxxxxxxx)`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autorelasespool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I have added the QuartzCore framework to the project as well. What am I missing over here? and what direction should I generally go in when such errors occur (because the build succeeded, app seems to have crashed here)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradients on UIView and UILabels On iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)] autorelease];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = view.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

from: [Gradients on UIView and UILabels On iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931498)

this code can help your problem.

Comment: Ok so it seems that `CAGradientLayer` does not work with an array of `UIColor`. Instead a `CGColor` array is needed. A quick look into documentation confirmed this. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: i never used that color,so i have no idea,but i was trying tosolve your problem

Comment: add .CGColor to the end of the [UIColor] block. eg `[UIColor blackColor].CGColor`

Comment: @offset I totally did.

Answer (score 2):

In order to add a background gradient to a view I followed the tutorial at this link:

http://danielbeard.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/gradient-background-for-uiview-in-ios/

In my case I had a UITableView and wanted the gradient to be in the background. When I used the code below from the link my tableview disappeared.

```
-(void) ViewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {   
CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer blueGradient];
bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

On modifying my code as below, it was possible to have a background gradient and a tableview at the same time.

```
-(void) ViewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated {   
CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer blueGradient];
bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.tableView.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Isnt this just combining the other two answers into one?

Comment: It would also appear that you have another account that you use to upvote yourself.

Answer (score 0):

hey check out this guy's blog here. This helped me quite a lot! I modified the class as per my requirements and VOILA!

http://danielbeard.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/gradient-background-for-uiview-in-ios/