# drawing shadow using core graphic and using CALayer

Tags: ios, core-graphics, calayer

As far as I know we can use core graphic such as `CGContextSetShadowWithColor` to draw a shadow. However, we can also use CALayer to show the shadow as well.

**Question :**

what are the differences between 2 of them. Are there any rules to determine when we use core graphic to draw a or when we use CALayer to do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to say that using `CoreAnimation` is always preferred over `CoreGraphics`, since it's more high level, and abstracts the low-level details of drawing the shadow. (It may also allow apple to optimize the shadow drawing without hurting your code syntax).

However, there are times where you are overriding `drawRect:` anyways, and you have very specific use for the shadow, not the whole view's layer. You might wanna use `CoreGraphics` shadows here.

One last note, `CoreAnimation` gradients are much faster when rendering, take my word for it. I used it on `UITableViewCell`, and the scroll performance significantly increased, as opposed to using `CoreGraphics` Gradients. [That comes at a price, though. It's a bit worse-looking.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4676479/456434)