# iOS 5 AppStore detail page background color

Tags: ios, background, app-store, uicolor

What is the UIColor of this the AppStore detail page of the iOS 5- AppStore(http://elec.widgetspad.com/uploadfiles/elecwidgetspadcom-1348171101/apple-approving-ios-5-app-updates-already_1.png)?
Anyone having an Idea?

How can I create such a UIColor with 2 colors overlapping each other?

Thanks

Comment: If you are talking about the background color - This is the one:

    [UIColor colorWithRed:211.0f/255.0f green:212.0f/255.0f blue:214.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor]

Comment: Yeah, I reaized that, but it has this kind of shadow at the top.

Comment: I see: The color varies from RGB: 162,163,164 and increases by 1 on each RGB and after middle it stays at 212, 214, 214

Comment: yeah, and how can you do that programmatically?

Comment: I believe you need to play around with Gradients a bit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone/1931498#1931498 :)