# UIView Background Gradient With Interface Builder View

Tags: ios, ios6

I want to use a gradient as the background for a UIView. I know this is typically done with images and the `backgroundColor` property. However, I want to learn how to do this in code. Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931498/99683 I can create a `UIView` programmatically and give it a gradient layer. This works great.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 340, 280, 100)];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = view.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor], nil];
[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

However, if I place a view in Interface Builder (with background set to clear) and try the same thing the gradient never shows up.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient2 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient2.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
gradient2.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];
[self.containerView.layer insertSublayer:gradient2 atIndex:0];
```

Is there something else I need to do in IB or code to make this work?

Comment: Hi. What is "self" here ? an UITableViewCell? My best recommendation is to implement an UIView and do the drawing in the drawRect method :) and then use this UIView subclass in your XIB if you want it that bad :-) but it's just a personal recommandation, I'm not a big fan of IB.

Comment: `self` is the view controller and `containerView` is the IB outlet to the `UIView` object. Yea, at this point I'm wanting to do this more as an academic exercise than anything else. I'll have to try the subclass and `drawRect` method.

Comment: The subclass and `drawRect` method is working beautifully for me BTW. Thanks @Vinzius! Still curious to know if there's a more straightforward way to do gradients with IB views though. :)

Comment: Ok cool :-) well, doing subclass and using them in IB isn't bad, that's the minimum for a better life xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem, but finally figured out that the UIView hasn't been created at the point in the code where you're trying to set background gradient which I guess in your case might be one of the following -*viewDidLoad* or -*viewWillAppear* because of which

> self.containerView.bounds will be {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

Instead, you should set the gradient layer inside

> viewDidAppear

at which point the views have been created.

Answer (score 1):

This library supports to set a gradient background in Storyboard using by IB_DESIGNABLE / IBInspectable.

It's really useful.

https://github.com/recruit-mtl/EXTView/