# Gradient border in Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cgcontext

How to set a border color as gradient? Let's say I want it from black to white.

```
[layer setBorderColor: <some gradient object>]?

[layer setBorderColor: UIColor[graident..].CGcolor]?
```

Comment: A walk-around way is to lay a larger gradient background image below, and add UIControl you need above the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a border, you could insert a `CAGradientLayer` sublayer to your view.

Have a look here on SO: [Gradients on UIView and UILabels On iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone/1931498#1931498)

Answer (score 4):

```
UIColor *gradientColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"borderColor.png"]];
layer.borderWidth = 10;
layer.borderColor = gradientColor.CGColor;
```

the `borderColor.png` should be a gradient png fit for your view. Maybe it is not a perfect way , but it can use and deal with the problem easily.

such as my test (I do not have a gradient png , just use a normal png have a test , the border color is my pngs color , your should make your png is a gradient png) : [image]