# Drawing a line with more than one color iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am drawing a line which color is black. But i want to be more than one color in this line. For example; 40% yellow, 30% black, 30% blue. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks for your answer and interest.

Here is my code;

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height/2)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height/2)];

CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
pathLayer.frame = self.bounds;
pathLayer.path = path.CGPath;
pathLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
//pathLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapSquare;

pathLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
pathLayer.fillColor = nil;
pathLayer.lineWidth = 15.0f;
pathLayer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
//pathLayer.lineDashPattern = @[@15];

[self.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];

}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean like a gradient. See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1931498/1176870

Comment: But if i use gradient, colors passing softy to each other. I want to pass to next color directly.

Comment: u cant have different colors for one beizier path!!!! You need to have different bezier path for different colors!!

Comment: Okey, thanks for your answers :)