# Misplaced CAGradientLayer on iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cagradientlayer

I have a few `UILabels` with colored background and I added `CAGradientLayers` to them like below.

```
CAGradientLayer * gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        (id) [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.3].CGColor,
                        (id) [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.3].CGColor, nil];
gradientLayer.frame = label.bounds;
gradientLayer.cornerRadius = label.layer.cornerRadius;
[label.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

On iPhone 4 and iPhone 5s it looks perfect, but on iPhone 6s the `CAGradientLayers` are misplaced horizontally like the following screenshot.

[image]

This problem happens for UIButtons as well.

I am running iOS 9.3.

Comment: Where in you view/view controller lifecycle is that code placed?

Comment: If the labels' and buttons' frames change, then the gradient layer needs to change with it. For example, if the labels are laid out with autolayout and the view is rotated, the gradients' frame will need to be updated. You can do this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` on your view controller, or subclass the labels/buttons with gradients in them and update the gradients frame in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: @beyowulf the code is in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @keithbhunter the labels and buttons don't change and this is a portrait only app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is deal with autolayout constraints. This swift code represents what you need to do at `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.3).CGColor,
                                UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.3).CGColor]
        gradientLayer.frame = button.bounds
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = button.layer.cornerRadius
        button.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        gradientLayer.frame = button.bounds
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't I need to add the gradientLayer to the button?